# How to make a function around dict.update() that similarly can take both positional and key-word args?

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax, function-call

The built-in update function to dictionaries can take either, tuples or dictionaries as arguments. I want to make a function around it that also can take both tuples and dictionaries.

```
parDict = {}
parDict['a'] = 1
parDict['b'] = 2
parDict['group1.a'] = 3
```

I can do both:

```
parDict.update(a=2, b=3)
parDict.update({'group1.a':4})
```

Define a function

```
def par(**x):
    parDict.update(x)
```

I can do

```
par(a=2, b=3)
```

but I cannot do

```
par({'group1.a' : 4})
```

The error message is: par() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

In my eyes {'group1.a' : 4} is a key-word argument (although 'group1.a' is not an identifier but a string. The same error text if I address the other parameter {'a': 4} which has an identifier.

If I in the function declaration change par(**x) to par(x) then I can do

```
par({'group1.a' : 4})
```

but not

```
par(a=2, b=3)
```

I can of course make an alias

```
par = parDict.update
```

This works for both types of arguments, but I want to do some more and really need a function here (to make some checks before update).

How should I improve the argument declaration, or the code, of par() to handle both types of arguments?

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to pass both a dict and kwargs at the same time? Like `parDict.update({'group1.a': 4}, a=2, b=3)`? Because the original method already supports that.

Comment: No, I want simply to do what I can do with parDict.update(). Either use tuples or a dictionary as arguments. Typically you need to switch from tuples to dictionary when the key is a string and not an identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand well, this would work for you:

```
def par(*args, **kwargs):
    ## Merge positional and keyword arguments
    kwargs.update(*args)
    ## Do checks and stuff on kwargs before update
    # ....
    parDict.update(kwargs)
```